# Missing DLL's and Custom Actions when using MSBuild to build Visual Studio Solution with InstallShield Pro Project

Tags: c#, msbuild, installshield

I am currently trying to automate our .NET builds and have currently run into a snag. When building the project in Visual Studio on a machine with a InstallShield 2016 Professional License, everything builds fine. However, when trying to use MSBuild to build the VS Solution on a machine with InstallShield 2016 Standalone, the resulting MSI does not have a required DLL or a Custom Action. Meanwhile, trying to build the .ism using Iscmdbld results in the inability to find the Primary Output of the csproj's, Even after building in Devenv

Answer (score 0):

If you are using project output groups (like Primary Output), your choices are limited. You have to use either the VS integrated build (via devenv), or MSBuild; iscmdbld is unable to resolve project output groups.

Your other alternative is to change from project output groups to using static (or dynamic) file links that don't require Visual Studio's knowledge. I tend to prefer static links, as it's easy to tell exactly what's in the project. More importantly, with static links you can't silently lose files that you'd previously added, thus it's easier to avoid potentially breaking component or upgrade rules.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this isn't too old to be of use.  InstallShield is the absolute worst, I know.

If you edit your .isproj in a plain-text editor, you'll see that it's just a regular MSBuild script.  You'll see that there is a lot of commented out stuff that explains (poorly) things you can add to it.  Find the ItemGroup that contains the explanation about "ProjectReference items" and add a node of the following form:

```html
<!-- The ProjectReference items refer to any Visual Studio solutions you want to automatically probe for Project Output Groups.  -->
<ProjectReference Include="..\Path\To\Your\Proj.csproj">
   <Project>{2d3f37cc-0e93-4673-a3df-59c556185f71}</Project>
   <Name>Name Of Project As It Appears in VS</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

After adding the above to all of my .isproj files, my automated build worked fine.  Why the idiots at InstallShield never saw fit to add this capability to the UI, I'll never understand.

Unfortunately, I don't have any answer to the Custom Action problem, if it's not related to the above.